# Openbox autostart.sh file not running all commands

Tags: 18.04, autostart, openbox, xinit

I am using Openbox 3.6.1 with xinit on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

As per normal procedure, i created an `autostart.sh` file to be run when Openbox starts up.

The file is located at `~/.config/openbox/autostart.sh`

The contents of the file are as follows:

```
   docky &
   tint2 &
   nitrogen --restore &
   xcompmgr &
   volti &
   conky &
```

When my desktop starts up, everything seems to work fine except docky.
It starts inconsistently, sometimes the autostart.sh file will get it running as a background process without any issues, other times the dock doesn't appear at all.

I have created a workaround, by creating options in obmenu for all the programs in my autostart.sh file, so with a simple right click i can manually start the software.

However im looking for a better solution to this problem, and if anyone can explain whether the issue is related to docky or to openbox itself i would appreciate the information.

Comment: It might be launching it too fast.  Try delaying it for a few seconds like maybe 3.  Change the command to `sleep 3; docky &`.  Or two seconds.  I have had to delay things on my system because they sometimes fail if I don't add on a delay.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance, i'll give it a shot.

Comment: docky has not been maintained for a while and isn't even available in 20.04.  I believe it relies on outdated dependencies.  It might be time to switch to another dock.  plank and latte are good replacements.